# Transcrypt with import statement

Tags: python, transcrypt

I have a Python file called `hello.py` which is:

```
import openpyxl

def operate_excel():
    file = 'dummy.xlsx'
    new_row = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']     # Older method was  .get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    row = ws.max_row + 1

    for col, entry in enumerate(new_row, start=1):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=entry)

    wb.save(file)
```

When I run it from Python directly, it works. However, when I tried to transcrypt it with following command it fails:

`python3 -m transcrypt -b ./Codes/js_excel_operations/hello.py`

And this command generates following output lines:

```
Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.7.16
Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0


Saving target code in: /Users/stuck/Codes/js_excel_operations/__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js
Saving minified target code in: /Users/stuck/Codes/js_excel_operations/__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js
Saving target code in: /Users/stuck/Codes/js_excel_operations/__target__/openpyxl._constants.js
Saving minified target code in: /Users/stuck/Codes/js_excel_operations/__target__/openpyxl._constants.js

Error while compiling (offending file last):
File './Codes/js_excel_operations/hello.py', line 1, at import of:
File '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py', line 8, at import of:
File 'openpyxl.reader.excel', line 62, namely:

Import error, can't find any of:
    ./Codes/js_excel_operations/drawings/find_images.py
    ./Codes/js_excel_operations/drawings/find_images.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/drawings/find_images.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/drawings/find_images.js
    /Users/stuck/drawings/find_images.py
    /Users/stuck/drawings/find_images.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/drawings/find_images.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/drawings/find_images.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/drawings/find_images.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/drawings/find_images.js
    /Users/stuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/drawings/find_images.py
    /Users/stuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/drawings/find_images.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drawings/find_images.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drawings/find_images.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyradio-0.8.8-py3.7.egg/drawings/find_images.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyradio-0.8.8-py3.7.egg/drawings/find_images.js
    ./Codes/js_excel_operations/drawings.py
    ./Codes/js_excel_operations/drawings.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/drawings.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/drawings.js
    /Users/stuck/drawings.py
    /Users/stuck/drawings.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/drawings.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/drawings.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/drawings.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/drawings.js
    /Users/stuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/drawings.py
    /Users/stuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/drawings.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drawings.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drawings.js
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyradio-0.8.8-py3.7.egg/drawings.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyradio-0.8.8-py3.7.egg/drawings.js

Aborted
```

So, what can be the problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

See [section 1.3](https://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/what_why.html#the-ecosystem-different-batteries) in the Transcrypt docs. In short, often you'll want to use JS third party libraries.

The underlying reason is that Transcrypt can't convert libraries with compiled components into JS. Also, within Transcrypt, all of the standard library hasn't been implemented, only some of the [essentials](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/tree/master/transcrypt/modules). For everything else, use JS libs.

Comment: Thank you man. so, as a following question, do you know any stable xlsx library for JS or what is your suggestions? How can I edit that damn file :) ?

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963273/js-library-to-create-formatted-xlsx-spreadsheets) with some options. Hope it helps.